# How to use Behat with CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, behat

We are toying with Behat to start writing specifications for our PHP applications. All step definition implementation examples are for plain PHP classes, but we are using CodeIgniter as a our prefered framework.

We rule out writing features and scenarios that are UX/UI oriented (that would abstract away the underlying framework) until later in the development stage, and would like instead to test the application layer by accessing the CodeIgniter models.

How do you get Behat to use these models? i.e. how do you integrate Behat with CI?

Answer (score 0):

[Download here Behat CI Test](https://github.com/daryl-williams/Behat_CI_Test)

Simple test with Behat and CodeIgniter. The CodeIgniter controller just displays a login page and returns a data array that use to make assertions. There are various debug statements printed with error_log, which Behat displays on stdout, to follow the flow of execution.

Comment: We want to carve out a **clean domain model** and do not intend to code any controller nor view beforehand. The **models** are the only things to be called from within the step definitions. What you suggest there is to start out early with controllers and views.

Comment: I don't find any tutorials more. Only Daryl Williams (https://github.com/daryl-williams) did this test. I suggest you to start with controllers.

Comment: Found this but haven't tested it yet as it seems very awkward: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Calling-CI-models-from-outside-script

Comment: @IhariR, test it. It looks good. Hope that you will find the best solution.

Comment: It happens so that our CI package has been integrated with my-ciunit for PHPUnit integration (the KenjiS version) and the following hack works perfectly up to now: At the top of the FeatureContext.php file, we require the CIUnit bootstrap file and from that point on one can just do something like $CI = &get_instance(); $CI->load->model("SomeModel");